# Emojis getting converted to "?"

Tags: database, mysql, phpmyadmin, encoding

Emojis in posts and comments on a 500+ posts blog get converted automatically into single question marks in irregular and untraceable intervals.

The respective tables `wp_comments` and `wp_posts` are configured to have a `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation, albeit in a `latin1` / `latin1_swedish_ci` database, which (to my understanding) shouldn't be a problem, as long as the tables are configured correctly, right?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I was searching for a solution for months on end now and I just can't pinpoint the culprit here. Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Check your plugins. Sometimes they will turn off functionality you expect. First disable the ones that change fonts, most likely the culprits.